# How to send python scrapy requests in order (From a list of websites->Website -> Extract Webpages -> Webpage (until done)-> Other Website -> .... )?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, google-sheets-api

The problem is that I want my spider to send requests to different websites and in between I have a callback that extract all the links of the current website domain and send requests to them and calls another callback function.

So, I want everything to be in order i.e.:

- first send req to first website
- then to its extracted links
- after that when it is complete then go to next website
- then to its extracted links

But scrapy is doing opposite :

- first it sends requests to the first 3 websites
- then it is sending requests to all the extracted links of all websites in a random manner

How can I avoid this behavior?

Note: I'm simultaneously updating the data on google spreadsheet so I need it to send requests in such a ordered manner.

I have tried providing priority parameter to the request but still remains the same.

Also I have set custom settings parameter `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1`

Comment: That's not under your control.  Perhaps you need to find a way to sort the results.  Either that, or you'll need to do the web requests yourself.  Tools are great when your need fits their model.

Comment: You should probably look into a framework that isn't asynchronous.